# Gitlab: How to trigger a script when a file is changed?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a repository in Gitlab and what I wish to have is a setup in which when a specific file in a specific branch is changed, I want a script/job to be triggered, which will read and make operations based on this new version of the changed file.

That script can be in another machine and be accessed through SSH, or it can be inside the same repository and be executed somehow.

Is there any way to do this with Gitlab CI/CD?

Edit: I'm using *GitLab Enterprise Edition 11.2.3-ee aadca99*

Answer (score 1):

You can use [only/except](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlychangesexceptchanges) changes to do this.

It has been introduced in Gitlab 11.4 and it works with files and directories within your repository, example :

```
docker build:
  script: docker build -t my-image:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG .
  only:
    changes:
      - Dockerfile
      - docker/scripts/*
      - dockerfiles/**/*
      - more_scripts/*.{rb,py,sh}
```

Comment: Ok, I forgot to mention that I'm using _GitLab Enterprise Edition 11.2.3-ee aadca99_. Any solution for this version?

Comment: It's better to upgrade instead of finding workaround but if you can't, there is a bunch of workarounds in this [thread](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/19813)